How to enter user input in command line using jmeter
I am using this code i received handle is invalid error and stream closed error
def userInput = System.in.withReader { reader ->
    OUT.println 'Please enter test parameter'
    reader.readLine()
}

OUT.println('You have entered: ' + userInput)

vars.put('userInput', userInput)

Could you please provide the solution

This code:
def userInput = System.in.withReader { reader ->
  OUT.println 'Please enter test parameter'
  reader.readLine()
}

OUT.println('You have entered: ' + userInput)

vars.put('userInput', userInput)

reads the value from STDIN and stores it into ${userInput} JMeter Variable.
Here's the demo:

If this "doesn't work" take a look at jmeter.log file (it would be better to increase JMeter logging level to debug) and see if there are any suspicious entries.
Also there is an easier/better way of providing test parameters via command-line:

use __P() function like ${__P(userInput,)} in your test plan
provide the value via -J command-line argument like jmeter -JuserInput=foo when you run JMeter

